# How do I reference web root in .htaccess RewriteRule variable while using RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

Tags: .htaccess

Here's what I am trying to do. I have a few scripts on a site I am rewriting the URLs to force them to use https://. What I then want to do, is rewrite urls when I navigate away from the HTTPS pages back to HTTP. Here's what I have now that is not working exactly the way I would like it to.

```
# For HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(register/|cms/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# For non-HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(about/|contact/)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem I am having is that while the pages like about/ and contact/ rewrite back to HTTP, I can't figure out how to reference the document root, so it unfortunately stays https://. I like using relative urls, so I would rather not go into my source and change everything to absolute if there is a simple htaccess solution.

**My question: How do I properly reference the web root in my RewriteRule?**

Also, is there a more efficient, catch-all way of doing what I am trying to accomplish that I just don't know about, because I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem. I am not super-familiar with .htaccess. I learn just enough as I go to do various Rewrite operations, as I will never have a need for the full features, and I find the documentation cumbersome and difficult to follow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for matching the root use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or combine them with the other rule

```
RewriteRule ^(about/|contact/|)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As to the catch all expect /register and /cms (that's what you mean right?). I think this should do the trick.

```
# For HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(register/|cms/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#prevent rules beneath this one in this htaccess file from being applied when url start with register of cms (doesn't do anything else)
RewriteRule ^(register/|cms/) - [L]

#don't force http for resources, to prevent partial encryption errors
RewriteRule ^(css/|images/) - [L]

# For non-HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Wow, I really should have known that leaving the reference blank would be the reference to the root. Thanks for that. Unfortunately, just adding that blank reference to the root causes my register page to only be partially encrypted (which to someone using firefox, looks like its not encrypted at all). I am going to guess that it is because I have references to images and other linked items that start from the root directory within my register page's HTML markup? Well, the rewrite is working on every page except the root, so I'll just use an absolute reference there and save myself the trouble

Comment: I edited the post not force http (instead of https) on certain directories (css and images in this example).

Comment: Brilliant! I have it working just the way I wanted it to now. Thanks!